# Разбиение единой строки на подстроки

Tags: java, android, строки

У меня есть txt файл на сайте,с которого я считываю информацию.

С помощью данного класса я считываю этот текст и разбиваю его на две строки:

```
   /**---------------------КЛАСС ДЛЯ СЧИТЫВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА ИЗ ФАЙЛА-----------**/
    public final class AsynchronousGet {
        private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        public void run() throws Exception {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://s***itus.com/hodite/text.txt")
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful())
                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
/*                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        }*/
                        Log.i("Good",responseBody.string());
                       // System.out.print(responseBody.string().toString());//СЧИТАННЫЙ ТЕКСТ
                        String string=responseBody.string();
                        int count=0;
                        String[] strings=new String[1];
                        for (String str : string.split("\n")) {
                            Log.i("str",str);
                            strings[count]=str;
                            count++;
                        }
                        //pushText(strings[0],strings[1]);
                        //(responseBody.string());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    /**------------------------------------------------------------------**/
```

Так выглядит текст,который я считываю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня выбивает ошибку постоянно:

```
11-29 17:24:31.316 6980-6980/com.example.com.shcherbuk I/Good: good
11-29 17:24:31.486 6980-7013/com.example.com.shcherbuk I/Good: Привет!
                                                               google.com
11-29 17:24:31.488 6980-7013/com.example.com.shcherbuk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                                         Process: com.example.com.shcherbuk, PID: 6980
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:379)
                                                                             at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:956)
                                                                             at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:92)
                                                                             at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:83)
                                                                             at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:109)
                                                                             at com.example.com.shcherbuk.MainActivity$AsynchronousGet$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:173)
                                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Ругается на эту строчку:

```
String string=responseBody.string();
```

Помогите подправить код,что я делаю не так?!

Comment: Разделитель, используемый в файле, может различаться. Он может быть, например, '\n', '\r\n', '\r' или некоторые символы юникода (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8). Думаю, что собственное решение будет заключаться в использовании регулярных выражений.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin то есть вы предлагаете поставить какой-нибудь разделитель,формата "/" и с помощью split разделить её?Точно)

Comment: "1\n 2 \r\n 3 \r 4 \\u000A 5".split("\\R").length возвращает 4. Т.е. символ \u000A тут плохо обрабатывается

Comment: @MikhailIonkin не понял,что вы написали

Comment: Я никогда не работал с этой либой, но есть предположение, что метод string не просто возвращает строку, а считывает данные откуда то там. Причем судя по исходному коду так и есть. Соответственн ваша проблема в том, что вы вызвали этот метод два раза. В первый раз при логировании, второй раз уже при записи в переменную.

Comment: Тоесть когда я вызываю responseBody.string(), он получается конектится к серву?И конектится можно только один раз?

Comment: Нет. Данные считываются из потока, и после считывания поток закрывается. Повторно из него считывать нельзя. Вы должны запоминать строку после вызова метода .string()

Comment: А split("\\R") означает разбиение не только по UNIX-совому символу переноса, но и по стандартному для Mac и PC